# dropdownlist does not default to selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code in my controller. Note that if the companyId is 4, I like that to be the default in my dropdownlist:

```
     var company = _conpanyService.companyLst().ToList();

     var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

     foreach (var item in company)
     {
         items.Add(new SelectListItem()
         {
           Text = item.CompanyName,
           Value = item.CompanyID.ToString(),
           Selected = item.CompanyID == 4 ? true : false
         });
     }         

     // I double checked the items list and it does have companyID of 4 set to Select to true. Not sure why it did not propagate to the view. 

     ViewBag.CompanyList = items;
```

Content of view:

```
     @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyList, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The issue is that even when I view the source code on the View, the selected does not come through. I am not sure why it is not being selected.

Comment: Does any of them get selected?  Forget, does the dropdown have a multiselect property?  Is it marking them True?  Do you need to invalidate and update the control?  Sidenote:  Selected will default to false or well it'll reset the value to false, if you just say Selected = (item.CompanyID == 4)

Comment: @tobeypeters None of them selected. I just have a drop down with all items on the list with the default being "Please Select". It is marking only 1 as true. I double checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  In Controller,

```
var company = _conpanyService.companyLst().ToList();
ViewBag.CompanyList = new SelectList(company, "CompanyId", "CompanyName", 4);
```

In View,

```
@Html.DropDownList("CompanyId", (SelectList) ViewBag.CompanyList)
```